# Determine bit depth of a video file

Tags: video, bit, depth

Im trying to find the bit depth of a particular video file. Does any one know of any tools i can use to find this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net) will show this.

There is a GUI available, or if you just want a command to extract only the bit depth you can use:

```
mediainfo --Output='Video;%BitDepth%' myvideo.mp4
```